# How do I overwrite the control_Change event for controls written on the fly?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with the following modules of code:

Class Module:  clsComboBox

---

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents MyComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox

Public Property Set cmboControl(cmboBox As MSForms.ComboBox)  
    Set MyComboBox = cmboBox  
End Property

Private Sub MyComboBox_Change()  
    If MyComboBox.Value = "2" Then  
        MsgBox "I will be so happy if this ever runs"  
    End If  
End Sub
```

---

UserForm:  UserForm1 (contains a single button, CommandButton1)

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()  

    Dim ctlcombobox As ComboBox  
    Dim clsobject As clsComboBox  

    Set ctlcombobox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "ComboBox1", True)  
    Set clsobject = New clsComboBox  
    Set clsobject.cmboControl = ctlcombobox  
    With ctlcombobox  
        .Top = 100  
        .Left = 5  
        .Width = 200  
        .Height = 25  
        .Visible = True  
        .List = Array("1", "2")  
    End With  
End Sub
```

---

I am trying to overwrite the combobox_change event with every new combobox I create on the fly.  However, the code is not working.  When "2" is selected on the comboBox, nothing happens.  What am I doing wrong?

example workbook:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ctr51lote86fbox/test%20combo%20box.xlsm?dl=0

*Edit*

Thanks, Tim, for the answer.  I did have to create a variable-length array to hold all of my comboboxes that I create on the fly in memory. (The original question was about a single combobox but in my actual worksheet, I am creating an unknown number at runtime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Dim clsobject As clsComboBox
```

This needs to be a global variable: in your current code it goes out of scope as soon as `CommandButton1_Click` exits.  It needs to persist if you want to capture later events.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will fix my userform, I'll let you know on Tuesday when I get back to work (don't have Office on home computer).  As an aside, if I create a variable length array of type userform, will this let me handle multiple userforms which I create on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as Tim says - just move that one line of code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim clsobject As clsComboBox  

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()  

    Dim ctlcombobox As ComboBox  

    Set ctlcombobox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "ComboBox1", True)  
    Set clsobject = New clsComboBox  
    Set clsobject.cmboControl = ctlcombobox  
    With ctlcombobox  
        .Top = 100  
        .Left = 5  
        .Width = 200  
        .Height = 25  
        .Visible = True  
        .List = Array("1", "2")  
    End With  
End Sub
```